# Matlab: Solve Exponential Equation with two unknown parameters

Tags: matlab, equation, numerical-methods, exponential

I have a Matrix called A. For example the following:

```
A = [1 2 3; 3 4 1; 2 4 4]
```

Now I have the following equation:
A(x,y) = (j^x)*(i^y)

j and i are normal values (dimension 1x1), not indices of a matrix. ^

Lets make an example:

```
A(1,1) = 1 (First value of the Matrix)
1 = (j^1)*(i^1)
```

And a second one:

```
A(1,2) = 3
3 = (j^1)*(i^2)
```

Is there a possibility to receive one solution for the two parameters using Matlab?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are x, y matrix indices? What are i, j?

Comment: Just two values which I need to find. They are not indices of a matrix.

Comment: But `A` is a matrix of fixed numeric values! So what is `A(x,y)`?

Comment: A is a matrix and x and y are the indices of the matrix. So for all elements of the matrix A the statement has to be fullfilled.

Comment: So three of the equations are like `4=(i*j)^2=i^3*j^2=(i*j)^3`? Because that doesn't look like it has a solution to me.

Comment: Should your second example be `3=(j^2)*(i^1)`? Oh I think you meant `A(1,3)` not `A(1,2)`, so it's alright.

Comment: It should be allright now. I am sorry.

Comment: You could always take `i` and `j` equal to `(A(x,y))^(1/(x+y))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that can find the best solution to your problem, if there is one. In this case, there is no reasonable solution, but defining `A` by `M([4 2])` (for example) does work reasonably well.

```
A = [1 2 3; 3 4 1; 2 4 4] %// the A matrix
[C,R]=meshgrid(1:3) %// create matrices of row/column indices
M=@(xy) xy(2).^C.*xy(1).^R %// calculates matrix of elements j^x*i^y
d=@(xy) A-M(xy) %// calculates difference between A and the calculated i^x*y^j matrix

r=fsolve(@(xy) norm(d(xy)),[1 1]) %// use fsolve to attempt to find a solution
d(r) %// show resulting difference between target matrix and solution matrix
norm(d(r)) %// norm of that matrix
M(r) %// show the solution matrix
```